# Como conseguir informações das metas tags de uma url externa

Tags: javascript, html

**Preciso principalmente pegar o content dessa tag:**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="www.meusite.com.br/imagem.jpg">
```

**e colocar no meu site como facebook faz nessa imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deve fazer isso via server side, com javascript provavelmente será barrado por fazer requisição em dominio diferente (CORS). Via php ou qq outra linguagem, precisará utilizar funções de DOM.

Comment: @CarlosZillner E quanto ao uso do https://crossorigin.me/?

Comment: legal, não conhecia....mas eu nao faria um site baseado nisso. Olha o que ele avisa: `I cannot guarantee the stability of the service, and you will probably experience service interruptions.`. Sou mais fazer algo que dependa 100% da minha própria aplicação. No caso seria fazendo um script server side que faz um acesso curl a url e usando funções de DOM para pegar. Se voce preferir usar este método que colocou, e tiver jQuery no seu projeto, eu sugiro que utilize o parseHTML https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Answer (score 0):

Tenta esse código.(Obs: clica no botãoObeter Meta Data e aguarde um pouco).
Esse código e so um exemplo será necessário edita-ló.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var query = 'select * from html where url="' + $('input').val() + '" and xpath="*"';
  var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

  $.get(url, function(data) {
    var html = $(data).find('html');
    $('#kw').html(html.find('meta[name=keywords]').attr('content') || 'no keywords found');
    $('#des').html(html.find('meta[name=description]').attr('content') || 'no description found');
    $('#img').html(html.find('img').attr('src') || 'no image found');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Type URL here" value="http://stackoverflow.com/" />
<button>Obeter Meta Data</button>

<pre>
  <div>Meta Keyword: <div id="kw"></div></div>
  <div>Description: <div id="des"></div></div>
  <div>Image: <div id="img"></div></div>
</pre>
```